# WPF DataGrid - I want know when the user is enter new Row

Tags: wpf, datagrid, row

I have two DataGrid, I want know when the user is enter new Row to check if he already select row in the other DataGrid if he don't selected then reject the new row.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this code u can used by event RowEditEnding in dataGrid by check if the row isNewItem:

```
private void dataGrid1_RowEditEnding(object sender, DataGridRowEditEndingEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Row.IsNewItem)
        {
            // here check if dataGrid2 have been selected row
            if (dataGrid2.SelectedItem == null)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("you have not Selected Vehicle,Please try again", "Error", MessageBoxButton.OK, MessageBoxImage.Error);
                 // here rebind dataGrid1 to clear new row
                dataGrid1.ItemsSource = salesData.T_Services.Where(x => x.FileNo == tbFileNo.Text);
                return;
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: When I had this question I could not get an answer anywhere and my research lasted for a long time. So I wanted to put the question here. Maybe I get an answer, but I knew the solution after thinking very well, so I put the answer quickly without explanation.
I'm sorry for that and i'm happy this code solve the question.